# Algorithm to "serialize" impulse responses

Tags: audio, finite-impulse-response, impulse-response, audio-processing

New user to dsp.stackexchange here. I'd like to know what's a quick and effective way to take 2 impulse responses and create one that's equivalent to both of these "in series" for audio applications. Basically i want to write a function that has:

```
inputs: impulse responses ir_a, ir_b
output: impulse response  ir_out
```

such that processing an audio signal with ir_out would be equivalent to processing it with ir_a then processing the output of that with ir_b.

The most "naive" (and off the top of my head, only) way to do this would be to run a sinewave sweep through both IR's sequentially, then deconvolve the result. However i'd like to know if there's a quicker and more efficient way that wouldn't trade off accuracy for processing speed, such as choosing a reasonable length for the sinewave sweep.

Answer (score 6):

You convolve the two impulse responses.

$$h_{cascade}[n] = h_1[n]*h_2[n]$$

Comment: So, just run the 2nd IR through the 1st one?

Comment: @delt - Start with a Dirac impulse for input. Convolve it with the 1st filter's impulse response. That's the 1st filter's output signal and input to the 2nd filter. Convolve that signal with the 2nd filter's impulse response to get the final output signal. This final output is also the combined filter's impulse response (by definition, because our input was a Dirac impulse and we've sent it through both filters in sequence)

Comment: @delt: yes. Or the other way around. Convolution is commutative.

Comment: @Hilmar Thanks. I just facepalmed so hard the back of my skull hurts!

Comment: @RainerP. Thanks. For the Dirac impulse in digital audio application, i guess i can use a single sample at max positive amplitude, followed by a bunch of zero samples?

Comment: @delt - Yes, you can. But you don't need to use an actual Dirac impulse because the convolution of a Dirac with h(n) is just h(n). In the end, my comment boils down to h1(n)*h2(n) as written in Hilmar's answer.

Answer (score 3):

### The answer

Like Hilmar describe in their answer all you have to do is convolve the two impulse responses to get

$$ h_{tot} \left[ n \right] = h_{1} \left[ n \right] * h_{2} \left[ n \right] \tag{1} \label{1} $$

### A wee bit longer explanation

I will assume you refer to *Linear Time-Invariant* (LTI) systems but if I am not mistaken this approach would work equally for time-varying systems as long as they are linear.

So, what you suggested is to run a signal $x \left[ n \right]$ through the system with impulse response $h_{1} \left[ n \right]$ and then its output through the system with impulse response $h_{2} \left[ n \right]$. The mathematical description of that would be

$$ y \left[ n \right] = \left( x \left[ n \right] * h_{1} \left[ n \right] \right) * h_{2} \left[ n \right] = y_{1} \left[ n \right] * h_{2} \left[ n \right] \tag{2} \label{2} $$

where the symbol $~ * ~$ denotes convolution. Since convolution is a linear operation you can rearrange the parentheses in *Equation* \eqref{2} to get

$$ y \left[ n \right] = \left( x \left[ n \right] * h_{1} \left[ n \right] \right) * h_{2} \left[ n \right] = x \left[ n \right] * \left( h_{1} \left[ n \right] * h_{2} \left[ n \right] \right) = x \left[ n \right] * h_{tot} \left[ n \right] \tag{3} \label{3} $$

where in this case $h_{tot} \left[ n \right]$ is given by *Equation* \eqref{1}.

### Subtleties

Now, if your systems are indeed LTI, then $h_{tot} \left[ n \right]$ will be time-invariant. In the case even one of your systems' responses $h_{1} \left[ n \right]$ and $h_{2} \left[ n \right]$ vary with time, your $h_{tot} \left[ n \right]$ will be different for different values of $n$, or at least will be possible to change as $n$ varies.